# Having a trouble loop for specific taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

Before, sorry for my bad grammar/English and bad code understanding

I'm testing a new website about short or series story with custom post type generated by `Writeshare` plugin. What I would like to achieve on my dynamic page is like this

Custom term (term name: Short Stories | slug: short term | tag ID: 2) from custom taxonomies (tax name: Format)

Post | Post | Post | Post | Post

Custom term (term name: Series | slug: series | tag ID: 3) from custom taxonomies (tax name: Format)

Post | Post | Post | Post | Post

My website is: https://qisa.xyz/ | and I'm using justread theme https://wordpress.org/themes/justread/

but I always failed when try to adding the tax to the loop, while custom post type (called WPWS content) successfully added to the home page via `pre_get_post` in `functions.php`

I've been trying modified the code trying to only get post from needed taxonomy in `pre_get_post function` and loop but nothing worked so far.

Now my code is consisting default first loop (all content from custom post type, worked perfectly) and second loop (modified to specific taxonomy, as I write this thread in 'nothing found' status

And what the best approach to achieve this. Adding new WP_query? or through `pre_get_post` function?

code in function.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'wpws_content' ) );
return $query;
}
```

now code in index.php

```
        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>



    </main><!-- #main -->

    <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main grid grid--4">

        <?php $temp_query = clone $wp_query; ?>

        <?php query_posts( 'taxonomy_name=short' ); ?>

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( $temp_query->have_posts() ) : $temp_query->the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
```

Update:

I tried implementing the solution from Manoj Webvertex, but that was sent me into technical error. Where did the code go wrong?

```
 <?php
        $post_type = 'post';
        // Get all the taxonomies for this post type $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

        foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :   
             // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
                $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

                foreach( $terms as $term ) :
                    $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$format&term=$short->slug&posts_per_page=5" );
                    if( $posts->have_posts() ):
                        while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
                            /*
                            * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                            * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                            * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                            */
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                    endwhile;
                else :  
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );  
                endif;
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$post_type = 'post';

// Get all the taxonomies for this post type $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :

        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );

        if( $posts->have_posts() ): 
            while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
        //Do you general query loop here
            endwhile;
        endif;

    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: ok, with my bad understanding of code it sends me into 'this site is experiencing technical difficulty' page.

Comment: $post_type = 'post';
 
 foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :
 // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
 $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

 // Get all the taxonomies for this post type $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
 
 foreach( $terms as $term ) :
  $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$format&term=$short->slug&posts_per_page=5" );
  
  if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
  
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );